# XDocument Descendant Selector using Wildcard?

Tags: c#, xml

I have some XML structured like this:

```
<form>
    <section-1>
        <item-1>
            <value />
        </item-1>
        <item-2>
            <value />
        </item-2>
    </section-1>
    <section-2>
        <item-3>
            <value />
        </item-3>
        <item-4>
            <value />
        </item-4>
    </section-2>
</form>
```

...and want to turn it into something sane like this:

```
<form>
    <items>
        <item id="1">
            <value/>
        </item>
        <item id="2">
            <value/>
        </item>
        <item id="3">
            <value/>
        </item>
        <item id="4">
            <value/>
        </item>
    </items>
</form>
```

I am struggling to turn the old XML into an array or object of values. Once in the new format I'd be able to do the following:

```
XDocument foo = XDocument.Load(form.xml);
var items = foo.Descendants("item")
    .Select(i => new Item
    {
        value = i.Element("value").Value
    });
```

...but in the current mess the xml is in can I wildcard the descendants selector?

```
var items = foo.Descendants("item"*)
```

...or something? I tried to follow [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703741/c-sharp-and-xpath-with-wildcard-attribute-name-and-specific-attribute-value) but failed to adapt it to my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah-ha! It did click in the end. If I leave the descendants selector blank and add in a where statement along the lines of what's in [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703741/c-sharp-and-xpath-with-wildcard-attribute-name-and-specific-attribute-value)

```
.Where(d => d.Name.ToString().StartsWith("item-"))
```

Then we get:

```
XDocument foo = XDocument.Load(form.xml);
var items = foo.Descendants()
    .Where(d => d.Name.ToString().StartsWith("item-"))
    .Select(i => new Item
    {
        value = i.Element("value").Value
    });
```

...and I'm now able to iterate through those values while outputting the new XML format. Happiness.